# NodeJS Object.subClass()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Check the source code at [Github](https://github.com/Peer5/ShareFest/blob/master/core/dataStructures/DoublyLinkedList.js). It reads `peer5.core.dataStructures.DoublyLinkedList = Object.subClass({...})`

I checked JS Object API but could not find Object.subClass method. And I coudld not find declaration of the method in the repo. Is it a NodeJS thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a NodeJS thing. It is defined in that repo in the file [lang_ext.js](https://github.com/Peer5/ShareFest/blob/a808231529ec81d7a5c9d84211d76d889d56bb40/core/util/lang_ext.js#L10) .